# Non integrable distribution manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider the three-dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^{3} \subset \mathbb{R}^{4}=\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and define
$$
D=\left\{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^{2} \times \mathbb{C}^{2}:\|z\|=1, w \perp z, iw \perp z\right\} .
$$
For each point $z \in \mathbb{S}^{3}$, consider the maximal complex linear subspace $D(z) \subset T_{z} \mathbb{S}^{3}=\{z\} ^{\perp}$. Prove that $D(z)$ has rank 2 and that $D$ is not an integrable distribution on $\mathbb{S}^{3}$.

$\textbf{Solution.}$ Notice that $D(z)=\operatorname{span}\{X, Y\}$, where
$$
X(z)=j z \text { and } Y(z)=k z .
$$
Here, $z=z_{1}+z_{2} i+z_{3} j+z_{4} k$ is the quaternionic representation of $z \in \mathbb{S}^{3}$. That is,
$$
X(z)=\left(-z_{3}, z_{4}, z_{1}, -z_{2}\right) \text { and } Y(z)=\left(-z_{4} ,-z_{3}, z_{2}, z_{1}\right) .
$$
In particular, you have $\operatorname{rank}(D)=2$. Furthermore, calculating the Lie bracket between $X$ and $Y,$ we have
$$[ X, Y](z) = X(Y(z)) - Y(X(z)) = 2 i z,$$
that is not linear combination of $X(z)$ and $Y(z).$

$\textbf{My question:}$ Why do $X(z)$ and $Y(z)$ generate $D(z)$? I can't show it. I tried to write $w \perp z$ and $iw \perp z$ means that
$$z_1 w_1 + z_2 w_2 + z_3 w_3 + z_4 w_4 = 0$$ and
$$ - z_1 w_2 + z_2 w_1 - z_3 w_4 + z_4 w_3 = 0,$$ but i have no ideia.

Comment: Compute $\langle iz, jz \rangle$ and $\langle iz, kz \rangle$

Comment: @Didier We have $\langle i z, j z\rangle = 0$ and $\langle i z, k z\rangle = 0,$ then $w \in span\{ jz, kz\}?$

Comment: $T_z\Bbb S$ is $3$ dimensional. In this vector space, $\Bbb R iz$ is one dimensional. Hence, its orthogonal supplement is $2$ dimensional. You have shown that $jz$ and $kz$ are orthogonal to $iz$, hence that $D(z) \subset \{iz\}^{\perp}\subset T_z\Bbb S$. Can you conclude now?

Comment: @Didier I got it, thank you! As for the  Lie bracket, $[X, Y](z)=X(Y(z))-Y(X(z))=2 i z$ is that correct?

Comment: Didn't do the computations, but it should be something like that yes